# How to get invoice id from order increment id

Tags: magento

I have order increment id like 100000096 and i want to get its invoice id, please help me to achieve this in magento, i have tried with

```
                 $incrementId = '100000096';
               $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($incrementId);
                   $invIncrementIDs = array();
                     foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
                         $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
              }
```

But it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

You are using order increment id in `load()` function, you have to use `loadByIncrementId()`.

Try to use this -

```
$orderid = '100000096'; // order increment id
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    $invIncrementIDs = array();
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
        $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($invIncrementIDs);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: you should check if you have invoices for this particular order.

Comment: You are using order increment id in load() function, you have to use loadByIncrementId(). Please see my updated answer

Comment: yes it is returning now thanks, but is this invoice id is same as in sales_flat_invoice table in database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$orderIncrementId = '100000004'; // your order increment id

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    $invIncrementId = array();
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
        $invoiceIncId[] = $invoice->getIncrementId();
    }
}


echo "<pre>";print_r($invoiceIncId);echo '<br>';
```

In order to get `Invoice id` from `Invoice incrementId`

```
$incrementId = $invoiceIncId[0];
$invoive = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$invoiceId = $invoice->getId();

echo "<pre>";print_r($invoiceId);exit;
```

Comment: is $incrementId = '100000096' order increment id?

Comment: and also it gives "Fatal error: Call to a member function getId()" error

Answer (score 0):

try this you will not regret

```
$order_id = "type_here_your_orderid";
$invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($order_id)
                ->load();
$invoice_id = $invoices->getData()[0]["increment_id"];
echo $invoice_id;
```

thats all.